Dynamic linking of SIMD wrapper library for different architectures?
This stackoverflow hints that the Eigen vector library will need to know the targeted ISA at compile time to compile the SIMD intrinsics. As we are running our application on different servers using different intel ISA's, some supporting only AVX2 while others support avx512, what is the advised way to go about if we want to continually deploy or app on the whole server cluster? I have identified two ways but maybe there are more:

We could wrap Eigen in two precompiled shared lib where one covers the avx2 and the other the avx512 case, picking at runtime (since it's a header only library)
We could statically compile the whole application for two ISA's and hand it out individually.

Are there more, maybe better alternatives?

Perhaps a combination of the two methods -- compile for both targets and have a simple bootstrapper program with the runtime logic to detect architecture that then runs the correct app. This way you don't have to keep track of all your deployment targets, and you don't have to go through the pain of wrapping everything.

I'm curious as to how much of a performance boost AVX512 gives on the Eigen vector library. Do you have benchmarks for AVX2 vs AVX512 speed on a platform that supports both? You might be able to live with just using the lowest common denominator of AVX2 unless the performance gain is really worthwhile.

possible duplicate: Building backward compatible binaries with newer CPU instructions support, Clarifications about SIMD in C

@phuclv If I read this blog post linked in that possible duplicate correctly, then  the optimization does not apply to sub-functions if they are not inlined. In that case, it is probably unreliable at best with Eigen since many of the more interesting functions, e.g. matrix-matrix multiplication kernels, are too large and are not chosen to be inlined by the compiler
